# LibGdx Game looks pixelated when executing exported .jar compared to launching it in Intellij. How is that possible?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx, game-engine

Today i tried to export my libgdx game as a .jar from Intellij using the command `gradlew desktop:dist`. Unfortunately the quality (resolution) of the game when launching the .jar file looks significantly worse compared to launching it straight from inside intellij ( DesktopLauncher ).

Does anyone have ideas, as to why this could be happening? Shouldn't it look exactly the same?
Thanks a lot!